# artificial slowdown

Tags: flash, apache, performance

I've got a flash clip that is known to behave weird if user has slow internet. Now I want to troubleshoot that. Is there a way to slowdown the load speed? Preferably with local apache or may be even with firefox only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is about loading static files (not loading dynamically generated xml etc.) you might want to try the download simulation feature built in the Flash IDE. Start by testing movie (control+enter), then use View menu to enable and configure the simulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Proxy on your PC to inspect packages and even slow down your connection. It's usefull for debugging. There are two simple solution:

- [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), not free, but very powerfull and has a trial.
- [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843) can simulate a slow internet connection. Here's a SO question about it: [Firefox plugin to simulate slow internet connection or limit bandwidth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473465/firefox-plugin-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection-or-limit-bandwidth)

In the stated question, there are some more hints and addons.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, plugin is great. Will definetly use it later =)

Answer (score 1):

As guerda stated, use a proxy, another alternative to `Charles` is `Fidler` it is free and available here: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/